# Google Maps V3 API --- I would like to get the county based off lat/lng when a marker is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Ok, this Question is 2 fold:

1. I would like to display an overlay showing counties on the google map...how can I do this?
2. I would like to get the county based off lat/lng when a marker is dynamically created.

I think question 2 is a bit more involved. Here is the code that I have thus far. Basically...a "job Marker" is created in 3 ways: 
   a. User types in address---address is geocoded, marker is set
   b. user double clicks on the map and marker is set---address is reversed geocoded
   3. user drags default marker to new area on map---marker set----address is reversed geocoded.

Here is the code:

```
    initialize();

    //Function for the autocomplete field for map
    $(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
       geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term + ', us' }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        jobMarker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
  });

    //when user drags job marker the new info is added. 
    google.maps.event.addListener(jobMarker, 'drag', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': jobMarker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
          $('#latitude').val(jobMarker.getPosition().lat());
          $('#longitude').val(jobMarker.getPosition().lng());
        }
      }
    });
  });


   google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dblclick", function(event)
    {


        // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
        jobMarker.setPosition(location);


        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': jobMarker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
          $('#latitude').val(jobMarker.getPosition().lat());
          $('#longitude').val(jobMarker.getPosition().lng());
        }
      }
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

First you can use [Google Map Overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons) to draw an overlay.

Second using the [Geocoding Request](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingResponses) you can get back an Response that contains an Address (which should include a County)

**Update**

Here is an example from the Geocoding Requestion link above:

```
{
  "types":["sublocality","political"],
  "formatted_address":"Winnetka, California, USA",
  "address_components":
  [
    {
    "long_name":"Winnetka",
    "short_name":"Winnetka",
    "types":["sublocality","political"]
    },
    {
    "long_name":"Los Angeles",
    "short_name":"Los Angeles",
    "types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]
    },
    {
    "long_name":"Los Angeles",
    "short_name":"Los Angeles",
    "types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
    },
    {
    "long_name":"California",
    "short_name":"CA",
    "types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
    },
    {
    "long_name":"United States",
    "short_name":"US",
    "types":["country","political"]
    }],
  "geometry":{
    "location": [34.213171,-118.571022],
    "location_type":"APPROXIMATE"
  }
}
```

"address_components" is an `Array` of `Object` that contains properties `long_name`, `short_name` and `types`.  "types" is an `Array` of `string` that contains values describing the `long_name` and `short_name`.  It appears you have to loop through each `address_components` looking for an `Object` where it's `types` has a string value of "administrative_area_level_2".

Comment: Although I have read through the documentation I am confused on how to get administrative_area_level_2 to populate: $('#area').val();